# Merge Sorted Array in leetcode: The in-place modification of list doesn't work

Tags: python, arrays

The link to the question: [merge sorted array](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-sorted-array/)

I don't know why my solution doesn't modify the list nums1 when exiting the function **merge**. Here is the code:

```
def merge(self, nums1, m, nums2, n):
    """
    :type nums1: List[int]
    :type m: int
    :type nums2: List[int]
    :type n: int
    :rtype: void Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
    """
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < m and j < n:
        if nums1[i] < nums2[j]:
            i += 1
        else:
            nums1 = nums1[:i-1] + [nums2[j]] + nums1[i-1:]
            i += 1
            j += 1
    if i == m:
        nums1 = nums1 + nums2
```

Comment: You aren't modifying nums1, you're creating a new list and calling it nums1. Saying nums1 = (whatever) doesn't change whatever nums1 used to be, it just creates a new lists and assigns it to the variable nums1 (erasing whatever other assignment existed in that scope).

Comment: So when I exit this function, the list named nums1 which I created in this function will not be saved in memory any more. Is that right?

Comment: Because of the last line, yes

Comment: to replace the content of the list in place: `nums1 = ` -> `nums1[:] = `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lists are mutable, so you can create the behavior that you are looking for.  What you need to do is to assign new values to specific indices in nums1.  When you use splicing you are in fact creating new lists.  Use list functions like `[].insert()`, `[].pop()`, `[].extend()` to achieve the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: for the record you could probably complete this problem using only `insert()` and `pop` if I understand what you are trying to do correctly. Anytime the item in list2 is smaller than the item in list1, `list1.insert(i,list2.pop)`  assuming they are sorted.

Comment: Yes. Instead of using the `nums1 = nums1 + nums2`, I just modified the list by changing the elements in the list one by one like `nums1[m + n - 1] = nums1[m - 1]` and it works. Thanks for help.

Comment: Sure thing, would appreciate an upvote if you felt we helped!  Glad you got it!

Comment: My account doesn't have enough reputation to up vote : (

Comment: ah, I believe you can "accept" the answer and that would net me a few points.  Either way, I'll survive.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Solution:
def merge(self, nums1: List[int], m: int, nums2: List[int], n: int) -> None:
    """
    Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
    """
    nums1[:]=nums1[:m]
    for num in nums2:
        nums1.append(num)
    
    nums1[:]=sorted(nums1[:m+n])
```